# Access to a method of Object C in an Object B both created by Object A

Tags: c++, object

I think the problem is quite basic and there was the same Question for sure somewhere here but i wasn't able to find.

So here is the Problem. Top has access to MyCircle and calls the SetSize function. But MyCircle has no access to MyRect.

I am able to access MyRect if i am providing a pointer to MyRect within the Constructor of MyCircle, but i think there should be another way. Maybe i just got it wrong at all :( Thanks for your help.

in the

```
class Top{
   public:
      Rect   myRect;
      Circle myCircle;
      void Run();
};

class Rect{
   public:
      int size;
};

class Circle{
   public:
      int size;
      void SetSize(int buffer);
};

void Circle::SetSize(int buffer){
    myRect.Size = buffer;
}

void Top:Run(){
    myCircle.SetSize(10);
}
```

Comment: Why not pass it as parameter? Also, if a `Circle` needs to change the size of a `Rect` when changing its size, you are doing something wrong: Both classes have nothing to do with each other, don't couple them.

Comment: can you explain the relationship you're trying to achieve between these 3 objects ? Why does `Circle` need to be able to set `Rect`'s size ? Why can't `Top` do that ?

Comment: Top can do it, for sure but i was wondering if there is a way Circle can do it  in an "accepted way"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't pass a rectangle to a circle class, the circle should have no knowledge about the rectangle (or vice versa).

Instead make a function  in Top using both the circle and rect and act on that.
I don't know exactly what you want to do, but suppose you want to set the sizes equally. Than make e.g. a SetSize method in Top setting the sizes for both the circle and rectangle:

e.g.

```
 class Top{
    public:
       Rect   myRect;
       Circle myCircle;
       void Run();

       void SetSize(int size)           
 }

 where SetSize is implemented as:

       myRect.SetSize(size);
       myCircle.size = size;
```

It's always better to put code handling multiple derived objects in the base class instead of in one of the children. If there will be too much (or unrelated) functionality in the base class, create a different class (like SizeHandler).

btw, it's better not to use public properties but always get/set methods.

Comment: i was using things in top like `mycircle.SetSize(myrect.size);` i was just wondering if i could implement this directly into mycircle, but as i think of it it makes no sense in gerneral, sorry haha thanks for the reply. problem solved